# Changing the en.yaml for another one in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, yaml, language-translation

I managed to get a fr.yaml. I want this to be the default, an old Rails 2.2 tutorial says to add:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :fr
```

in `environment.rb`

It does not work, my rails server crashes on this config line.

What is the syntax for this setting in Rails 3? I do not want a multi-language app, I want to use only the french settings.

Comment: When you say it "crashes", what's the specific error you get? (post the backtrace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails3, you add this line to `application.rb`

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :fr
```

Answer (score 1):

This goes in `config/application.rb` in rails 3.